Why is my Conditional Formatting rule not working on some rows?
I have checkboxes in Column I and the following conditional formatting rule:
=AND($I13=TRUE,$A13<>"")

The rule is correctly applied to Row 13 when I13 is checked, but when I14 and I15 are checked it isn't applied to Rows 14 and 15.
What could be causing this?

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result. You can Make an anonymous sample document

Is TRUE supposed to be the cell's content? If so, it's a string, and needs to be quoted. Use $I13="TRUE" instead. For future reference, please post sample data in a markdown table, so we can see specifically what you're asking. Don't post a link to the spreadsheet alone, though. For the reasons why, see the [tag:google-sheets] tag wiki.

Try any of the following:
=$I13 * LEN($A13)

=$I13 * ($A13<>"")

=AND($I13, LEN($A13)) 

=AND($I13, $A13<>"") 

If the formulas above return FALSE for any row and Column I is checked, then the two most likely explanations are:

Column A is not empty.
You can test a range of cells to check if they're empty using the following formula. Modify the range rng to fit your needs:
=INDEX(LET(rng,A14:A20,
   IF(LEN(rng),
     ADDRESS(ROW(rng), COLUMN(rng), 4) & " not empty",)))


Conditional format range mismatch
If your conditional format custom formula is:
 =$I13 * LEN($A13)

The range of the rule should also start in Row 13. For example,
=A13:I




Thanks, @Blindspots! I didn't work, though.
I am creating a new question with a spreadsheet containig the practical example.
